# How to create Hotmail "Sign in" button styles?

Tags: html, css

How can I create a button style like that of the "Sign in" button on [hotmail](http://www.hotmail.com)?

It looks like it uses some css3 gradient.  Styles and state similar to screen shot for hover, active, etc.?

Can somebody provide some example code?  Thx!

[image]

Comment: That's the standard Windows Aero button, not CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9bahD/  play more with colors, but you never know if it will work in all browsers

for more buttons http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css-buttons.html#

```
<a href="#" class="button blue">Log in</a>


.button {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; /* zoom and *display = ie7 hack for display:inline-block */
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin: 0 2px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: .5em 2em .55em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em; 
    -moz-border-radius: .5em;
    border-radius: .5em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

.bigrounded {
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
.medium {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: .4em 1.5em .42em;
}
.small {
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: .2em 1em .275em;
}


/* blue */
.blue {
    color: #d9eef7;
    border: solid 1px #0076a3;
    background: #0095cd;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00adee), to(#0078a5));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00adee,  #0078a5);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00adee', endColorstr='#0078a5');
}
.blue:hover {
    background: #007ead;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0095cc), to(#00678e));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0095cc,  #00678e);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0095cc', endColorstr='#00678e');
}
.blue:active {
    color: #80bed6;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0078a5), to(#00adee));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0078a5,  #00adee);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0078a5', endColorstr='#00adee');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradient buttons with states (active, hover): http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-gradient-buttons